# Every word is marked as misspelled in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

Why is that most of the words, almost 90 percent, are marked as misspelled words when there is no error? And the spellchecking suggestions don't even look like English.

I am using TeXstudio as my editor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! There is no way anyone will be able to answer this question as is. At the very least, you're going to need to say what your text editor is.

Comment: The program pdfTeX does *not* mark any word as misspelled, because it does *not* contain a spell-checker. Name the programs you are using (editor, IDE or whateever), the language, and maybe an example.

Comment: I am new to this software. Actually I am writing a document for a conferenc. I dont actually know whether it is pdfTeX. I couldnt post this question without a tag and I couldnt make a new tag as I am a newcomer.  My code begins like this \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}




\ifCLASSINFOpdf
 
\else
 
\fi


\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

Comment: Which is your EDITOR (the program you use to write your LaTeX code)?

Comment: I think texstudio is my editor. And language is English.

Comment: then your questions are about texstudio  it is presumably set to some other language but since you have shown no example it is hard to say. Certainly any spell checking is unrelated to (pdf)tex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the spellcheck language in the options:

`Options` -> `Configure TeXstudio` -> `Language Checking` (on the left) -> `Default language:`
and choose `en_GB` for British english, for example.

[image]

Another (quicker) way is to change it from the language options on the **bottom right** of TeXstudio UI.

[image]